# On Google search, is there a way to disable autocomplete but keep Instant?

Tags: google-search

Google Instant has gotten to a level of speed that makes it extremely usable. Now that I like it, I'd like to turn off autocomplete, which seems to get in the way of the Instant results, more than enhance the search experience.

Does anyone know a way to do this? I've found a few userscripts (see below), but they don't seem to get the job done.

- [Disable Google Autocomplete](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/100954)
- [Disable Google Autocomplete & Preview](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/98577)

Comment: Google has discontinued Instant Search.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have this combination currently

There are two url variables that you can use:

- complete
- instant

The issue is that you can turn off instant by adding `?instant=0` to the url you go to google with (set it as homepage to save typing). This doesn't disable autocomplete.

HOWEVER, if you set `?complete=0` it not only disables autocomplete, but it also disables instant.

I tried the following combination; `https://www.google.com/?complete=0&instant=1` and instant was still turned off for me.

**Side Note:** I didn't realize I wanted this to work until I tried to make it work.

Comment: "Side Note: I didn't realize I wanted this to work until I tried to make it work."
Yeah, doesn't it seem like this functionality would be perfect for anyone with a half way decent typing speed?  Most of the time the autocomplete throws me off from what I'm trying to type.  Or, at a minimum slows me down.

Answer (score 0):

In the Search Settings page http://www.google.com/preferences you can turn off Google Instant and use the old style.

For that you have to logged in google account.

Comment: This would seem to be the exact opposite of what is being asked for.